# jqgrid resize with parent control

Tags: jqgrid

I divided the page in two section, in one i have jqgrid with autowidth set to true like in below pic.

[image]

Now when resizing the divs using center bar, i want to resize the grid,

using below code i am able to resize but then scroll is appearing in grid which i dont want

Note: Already scrollOffset is set to 0.

$("#grid").jqGrid('setGridWidth', $("#gridarea").width() - 5, true);

Answer (score 0):

Try using the fluidjqgrid plugin. Its pretty good when it comes to making the grid fluid.

You can find it at this site: http://stevenharman.net/blog/archive/2009/08/21/creating-a-fluid-jquery-jqgrid.aspx